# How can I merge password logins in Passwords and Keys?

Tags: login, google-chrome, password, seahorse

I have multiple Logins in Passwords and Keys (presumably created by Chrome).

Is there any possibility to merge those so I have to unlock only one upon start of Chrome instead of multiple?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A bit old, but see if https://askubuntu.com/a/54933/158442 helps

Comment: Will give it a try! Was hoping for a more easy approach instead of fiddling with text files.